# React delay button event for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, input, onclick

```
    <input
      type="file"
      ref={ref => {this.ref = ref}}
    />
    <button 
      onClick={(e)=> { 
        const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 2000) //change to 1000 works
        })
        promise.then(()=> {
          console.log('clicking');
          this.ref.click();
        })
      }}
    >
      Click me
    </button>
```

When the `Click me` button is clicked, I need to do some additional actions (eg. prompt for facebook login or fetch data) before opening the input file explorer.

In this case, i set a 2 sec delay but the click no longer activates. Changing the delay to 1 sec actually works.

I supposed the event 'expired' after 1 sec so there's nothing i can do for my situation apart from making the user click again?

[image: Edit mqq3pyn129]

Comment: post your code in details

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows you are clicking on a file input in the resolve method. And the click is executing in a `resolve` method of a `promise`.

Please note that you cannot trigger `click` on `file` input from a function that is not directly initiated by a user action. Say the `click` is trigger on `onClick`, then click on file would be executed. Since you are executing with a delay on a function that is not related to user initiated action, the `click` on `file` input wont be triggered. **This is for security concerns**.

But in your question since you are mentioning that you want `prompt for facebook login or fetch data` which will work as they might be pure javascript related actions.

Comment: It works if i lower the delay from 2 sec to 1 sec though. So browsers implement it specifically so that if the delay is longer than 1 sec it wouldn't work?

Comment: When the user actually clicks on the button, and when your delay function executes within certain time, the browser assumes its a direct result of user action. So the dealy actually depends on the browser and one should not always relay on the 1sec timeout as there is no specific docs on those.

Comment: What i want to achieve is: 1. user click on upload button 2. prompt user to log in. 3. open file explorer automatically after user successfully log in. Guess there's no way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to "block" the execution of the file event until you perform some logic like log-in.
I would tackle it from a different angle, on the click event of the "dummy" button  i would open a modal or a login page / component asking to login while passing it another event handler.
On the login form submit event i will check my logic of authentication and only then decide if i want to trigger the open-file dialog event.
a very simple example based on the code you provided:

```js
const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const LoginPage = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Please login!</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="user name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showLogin: false
    };

    this.onBtnClick = this.onBtnClick.bind(this);
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
  }

  onBtnClick(e) {
    // if not logged in...
    this.setState({showLogin: true});
  }

  onLogin(data) {
    // check log in success logic etc...
    // if success
    this.setState({showLogin: false});
    this.ref.click();
  }

  render() {
    const {showLogin} = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={ref => {
            this.ref = ref;
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Click me</button>
        {showLogin && <LoginPage onClick={this.onLogin} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Facebook api doesn't expose the its log in components though...we call an api method and gets a promise...

Comment: inside a promise it wont work, i think it's a security issue. any way, each browser handles a programmatic click on file type inputs differently, so i suggests thinking on a different approach all together.